# iterate over inputs inside of a class with .each()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an invoice project that has a form with inputs for item name, price, qty and subtotal.   Users can add multiple invoice lines to the form. Each invoice line is identical.

The problem that I am having is that .each() is counting the instances of class="line" but only picking up the values from the first row of inputs: service[0] = firstServ service[1] = firstServ

I want it to count instances of class="line" and pick of the the values of the inputs within the inputs found within the .line row: service[0] = firstServ service[1] = secondServ

**Input row**

```
<tr class="line">
    <td class="text-center"><label class="csscheckbox csscheckbox-primary"> {{form::checkbox('tax', 1, null,  ['class' => 'tax', 'id' => 'taxable[]'])}}<span></span></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="serviceName" name="serviceName" class="name form-control" id="serviceName[]" placeholder="Service name"></td>
    <td class="text-right"><input type="text" class="qty form-control" id="quantity[]" placeholder="qty" value="1"/></td>
    <td class="text-right"><input type="text" class="price form-control" name="cost" id="price[]" placeholder="Price" /></td>
    <td class="text-right"><input type="text" class="subtotal form-control" id="sub[]" name="sub" value=""/></td>
</tr>
```

**Use of .each() to collect user inputs**

```
var service = [];
    $('.line').each(function(){
        var name = $('.name').val();
        var qty = $('.qty').val();
        var price = $('.price').val();
        var subtotal = $('.subtotal').val();
           if(qty !== '') {
              obj = {};
              obj.name = name;
              obj.qty = qty;
              obj.price = price;
              obj.subtotal = subtotal;
            service.push(obj);
            }
        });
```

TIA for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the current context using `this` and then find the elements in it:

```
 var service = [];
  $('.line').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).find('.name').val();
    var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    var subtotal = $(this).find('.subtotal').val();
    if(qty !== '') {
          obj = {};
          obj.name = name;
          obj.qty = qty;
          obj.price = price;
          obj.subtotal = subtotal;
        service.push(obj);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your script is, you are always targeting all inputs with class like `name` or `price` instead of targeting elements withing current `line`.

One approach you can take is to use .map() - note the use of `this` to filter only elements within in current `.line`

```
var service = $('.line').map(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var qty = $this.find('.qty').val();
    return qty === '' ? undefined : {
        name: $this.find('.name').val(),
        qty: qty,
        price: $this.find('.price').val(),
        subtotal: $this.find('.subtotal').val()
    }
}).get();
```